# What will be the value of this term in a Herbrand structure?

Tags: logic

I have a problem for my logical programming class.

I have a structure `H`, which is a Herbrand structure and `v` is the evaluation function. If the terms `f(x)` and `f(c)` have the same value in `H` with evaluation `v`, then what will be the value of the term `g(f(x), x)` in `H` with an evaluation of `v`. (this is the whole problem)

I can't seem to understand how we can have `f(x)` when Herbrand structures are supposed not to have any variables. Also, even if we substitute it, what will its value be? I asked a colleague of mine and he said that the `f(x)=f(c)` means that `x=c`, which I am not sure is correct. Is he right? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the term $g(f(x),x)$ in an [Herbrand structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrand_structure) $H$ for the vocabulary with *constant* $c$ and functions $f$ and $g$ is :

> $g(f(c),c)$.

The [Herbrand universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrand_structure#Herbrand_universe) for a first order language with the following vocabulary :

- constant symbols: $c$
- function symbols: $f(-), g(-,-)$

is $\{ c, f(c), g(c,c), f(f(c)), f(g(c,c)), g(f(c),c), \ldots \}$.

The [Herbrand interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrand_interpretation) is an interpretation in which every constant is interpreted as itself, and every function symbol is interpreted as the function that applies it.

Thus :

> $c^H=c$

and

> $f^H(c)=f(c)$.

Comment: Thanks. But what is the purpose of having them just be themselves? What is that used for?

Comment: @Mackiavelli - an interpretation is based on the assignments of "objects" to the terms of the language: objects are denoted by the terms (that acts like "names"). The Herbrand interpretation uses terms as objects, i.e. they denote themselves.